# Navigation properties in Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to create navigation properties between two tables using EF (.NET Core 2.0). I have Message that contains FromUser and ToUser (as message can be sent from one user to the other user) and User that contains information about user like name and email.

When I execute Add-Migrations, I receive the error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'Message.FromUser' of type 'User'. Either manually configure
>   the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
>   attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Can you, please, let me know how I should create these properties correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: *"it should be two collections, one for FromUser, the other for ToUser"* That's exactly what it needs. Then use two  `Entity` + `Has`  +  `With` to map collection navigation properties to their corresponding inverse reference navigation properties.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to specify Entity + Has + With in Configure method or do I have to do it in OnModelCreating? I wanted to use Configure because it adds all the information related to the given class in one place.

Comment: You can do it in `Configure` method. In that case there is no need of `Entity` call, the `builder` argument serves the same purpose. E.g. `builder.HasOne(m => m.FromUser).WithMany(u => u.SentMessages)` and `builder.HasOne(m => m.ToUser).WithMany(u => u.ReceivedMessages)` Just note that this model introduces *multiple cascade paths*, so you have to turn off cascade delete for at least one of the two relationships (`.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restict)`)

Comment: Just to make it clear - do I understand correctly that I need to specify it only on one side, i.e. define builder.HasOne(m => m.FromUser).WithMany(u => u.SentMessages); in Message but do not define builder.HasMany(m => m.SentMessages).WithOne(u => u.FromUser); in User?

Comment: Yes. Single relationship always has two ends, but it's still a *single* definition, hence has to be configured only in one place.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my original question because I still receive the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't though. Are you sure the `MessageConfiguration` class `Configure` method is called?

Comment: Sorry for so many questions but I think this may be the problem. Where and how should I call it? Is it modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration in OnModelCreating? I've tried "modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<MessageConfiguration>(new MessageConfiguration());" but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ok, I found it. It should be: modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MessageConfiguration());

Comment: Exactly :) Now everything should be ok.